# Get iframe's element by attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, element

all, I`ve a question about get iframe's element by attribute using javascript.

1.html

```
<iframe id="if" src="2.html">
<div attr="test">
```

2.html

```
<div attr="test">
```

I`ve already known that if parent page want to get the its element by attribute, we can use jQuery like

```
$("div[attr='test']")
```

But how can parent get it's iframe's element by attribute?

Please write some simple code for explain, great thanks!

Jarod

I`ve found out a solution and test fine:

```
$("iframe[data-label='if']").contents().find("div[attr='test']");
```

Comment: old question, but worth noting that the html is likely malformed or OP is trying to do a DOM lookup in the `iframe` from the parent window, which is effectively impossible

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not totally off:

```
$("iframe div[attr='test']")...
```

Or with `id`:

```
$("#if div[attr='test']")...
```

Comment: I've another question, if the iframe has no id but only a attribute, how can I do this?

1.html

<iframe attr="if" src="2.html">
<div attr="test">

2.html

<div attr="test">

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried?

```
window.frameElement.getAttribute("data-media");
```